# Fix image in image tag in Html

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am making a html page using knockout.js and bootstrap , in which I am adding an image in image tag as shown in code below.

```
    <img class="media-object image-size" data-bind="attr:{src: headlineImage}"/>
```

The problem is that my image does not covers my image tag completely, there is some white background coming in image background which I don't want. I want to completely fill my image tag. any solution for this.[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ascMC.png)

Comment: can you create a snipept with relevant code?

Comment: Is the img surrounded by a container?

Comment: no. It is just an image tag with an image in it.

Comment: try width:100% and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you

`<img class="media-object image-size" data-bind="attr:{src: headlineImage}" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>`

Comment: Yes this solution has worked, thank you for sharing answer.

Comment: If it helped why you are not accepting this answer?